# Any problems with this exception handling approach?

Tags: java, exception

We need to have two functions. They do the same thing but one handles the exceptions and one throws the exception.  Note: If to handle exception, the exception has to be handled in the commonFunc() below. It would not work to handle the exception in functionHandlesEx() because to handle the function it needs the variable only available in commonFunc().  In order to re-use code, we got the following.   Do you see any problem with it (I can see one problem is: the function throws exception but actually no exception is thrown when isExceptionHandled is true----but Java allows this)?  Any better way to do this?  We are in Java 6.  Thanks.

```
public void functionThrowsEx() throws Exception e
{
  commonFunc(false);  //false means does not handle exception
}

public void functionHandlesEx()
{
  try
  {
    commonFunc(true); //true means handle exception
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    // do nothing as exception handled
  }
}

private void commonFunc(final boolean isExceptionHandled) throws Exception
{
  try
  {
    ....
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    if (isExceptionHandled)
    {
       //handle the exception
    }
    else
    {
       throw e;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If there isn't a real exception, it doesn't matter if isExceptionHandled is true or false, it won't be called

Comment: It appears valid.  I assume the try/catch in functionHandlesEx is a formality, to keep the compiler from griping about "exception not handled or thrown".  (Thank you, Mr Goodenough!)  The "real" handling is done in commonFunc.  And you need the two different outer functions so that functionHandlesEx doesn't need a `throws` clause.

Comment: (I can't think of any way to make it any simpler.  And in Java rethrowing the exception should work cleanly.  (Not so much in some other environments.))

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an overly complicated approach to handling the exception.  I understand its toy code to show what you are doing, but I haven't encountered many reasons to create nested calls in order to handle exceptions.

Ideally, the code that can cause the exception should have the means to handle the exception in it, using try...catch, and maybe finally.  This logical flow looks like it would be pretty complex in a non-trivial application, and would lead to increased complexity and difficulty in debugging.

Comment: Note that the two separate outer functions are needed so one can have a `throws` clause and the other not.

Answer (score 0):

You should get rid of the two functions, and avoid nesting try/catch blocks. If you must nest them, make it has straigtfoward as possible by keeping the logic in the same method.

From the code, I'm guessing you want to handle the exception differently based on the state of the program. This code is  too complex, and will be difficult to understand for a non trivial app. A better way would be to keep functionHandlesEx and put the exception recovery logic in the handler function.

```
public void functionHandlesEx() {
try {
   //logic here;
  }
 }
catch (Exception e) {
 if(iWantToHandleException) {
    //handle exception    
   }
  //do nothing otherwise. Use the finally block for anything else they have in common.
  }
}
```

This is much simpler to understand, and it shouldn't be too hard to refactor it into this form.

Comment: The OP explained that the function needs to be handled inside commonFunc in order to access internal data.